# How to print html from angularjs expression?

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink

Lets suppose I want to print the following html:

```
<a href..?> </a>
```

and I have it inside some expression.

how can I print it so it will be clickable using `{{x.something}}` in angular js `ng-repeat`?

Comment: using `<div ng-bind-html="x.something"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 1 of 2 things.

1. Use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service with the `ng-bind-html` attribute.  `$sce` requires that you call `$sce.trustAsHtml()` around the html content before binding to the UI.
2. Use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) (by adding it as a dependent module) and then use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: thank you, i used the $sce option.
thank you very much